# When replicating with timescaledb and postgresql 12, the container shuts down when pg_basebackup is used

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, replication, timescaledb

I am trying to replicate between one timescaledb running as a docker container on Gcp and a timescaledb running as a docker container on the local server.

The postgres version is 12 and the experiment is finished when the data is small.

However, if there is a lot of data to be replicated, when the pg_basebackup command is executed in the slave-side db, the container keeps shutting down and replication is not performed.

The container is shut down before replication.

---

The docker image and command used are as follows.

```
docker run -d --shm-size=8G --name timescaledb -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="mypassword" -v timescale_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data timescale/timescaledb-postgis:latest-pg12
```

When executing commands in slave container

```
bash-5.1# rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/data/*
bash-5.1# pg_basebackup -h 34.64.147.133 -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -U rep_user -P
Password:
 582712/9674644 kB (6%), 0/1 tablespace
```

It shuts down at about 30%, and the log at shutdown is as follows.

```
2021-09-14 07:52:16.369 UTC [25] LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.369 UTC [25] LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.379 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.389 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.399 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.410 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.420 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.430 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.440 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.450 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.460 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.471 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.481 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.491 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.501 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.511 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.521 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.531 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.542 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.552 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.562 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.572 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.582 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.592 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.602 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.613 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.623 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.633 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.643 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.653 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.663 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.674 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.684 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.694 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.704 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.714 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.724 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.734 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.745 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.755 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.765 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:16.775 UTC [24] LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2021-09-14 07:52:16.775 UTC [24] WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [1] LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [1] LOG:  performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [1] LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [1] LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [24] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [24] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [24] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2021-09-14 07:52:21.261 UTC [25] LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat/global.tmp": Permission denied
2021-09-14 07:52:21.274 UTC [1] WARNING:  online backup mode was not canceled
2021-09-14 07:52:21.274 UTC [1] DETAIL:  File "backup_label" could not be renamed to "backup_label.old": Permission denied.
2021-09-14 07:52:21.453 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

How can I run replication on postgresql db made of docker container?

Comment: Hello, there's a long discussion of how TimescaleDB backs up in a blog post... it would be worth reading up on that I think as it addresses your question even if not your specific circumstance. https://blog.timescale.com/blog/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-postgresql-on-kubernetes-continuous-backup-restore-validation-on-timescale-forge/

_Transparency:  I work for Timescale_

Comment: can you share dockerfiles of timescaledb you use?